# Asymmetric encryption in local mode?

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm writing a desktop application and everything is done **locally** in it. In this software I need to encrypt some files. Are there any advantages to use asymmetric vs. symmetric encryption algorithm in local mode?

Comment: On which language exactly?

Comment: For asymmetric encryption you'd have to deal with two keys. IMHO if everything is done on the local machine, I think symmetric encryption would be ok. But since the question is rather language agnostic, it could also qualify for http://security.stackexchange.com/ or http://crypto.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @SonerGönül Is there any difference between languages about encryption algorithms? I'm Programming on C#.

Comment: @AliSepehri.Kh _Well_ I'm not sure but if your question doesn't depens on language, you shouldn't use both tags IMHO.

Comment: Is this encryption just for the sake of saying "we do encryption" or do you actually have specific threats that you're trying to protect this data against? If the latter, it would help if you could outline those threats.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: No, We actually have threats about it. We are encrypting our assemblies and load them in run-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be any technically or security motivated reasons for using asymmetric encryption instead of symmetric.

The main motivation should be whether or not you want the behaviors associated with asymmetric encryption (Public/Private keys).  The primary behavior would be the ability to let different people decrypt the files, but not be able to encrypt them themselves.

From a security standpoint they are about equal, and in most cases you wouldn't encrypt the whole file with an asymmetric algorithm anyway.  Instead you encrypt the file with a symmetric algorithm, then use an asymmetric algorithm to just encrypt that key, and include that in the file too, so someone with the private key can decrypt the whole file.

From a technical standpoint, symmetrical encryption is easier, and faster, so I don't see there being any advantage with asymmetric there.

Comment: Thanks for your really helpful answer. I agree that encrypting the key increase the security but in this case also cracker can find private key to decrypt files, Am I right?

Comment: Yes.  If your application is truly self contained, and you are not asking the user for a password, then technically you are only obfuscating the file not encrypting it.  Someone with access to your hard drive could decrypt the file.  The standard solution is to ask the user for a password and use that to generate the key for symmetric encryption (like TrueCrypt does), or use it to encrypt the private key (like PuTTY does).